# Merge two rows into one after a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm given data on the following form from an external program, thus I have no way to modify the way it represents the elements. The idea is that a single element consists of (xy) and is for some (obscure) reason translated into two different rows when the program outputs the measures. I would like to turn it back into a single row with the sum of the measure as the result. Below is the data-format.

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    Manager |    x    |    y    | Measure |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| A          | Left    | Right   | 10      |
| A          | Right   | Left    | -9      |
| A          | Venstre | Hojre   | 4       |
| A          | Hojre   | Venstre | -1      |

                     ...
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    Manager |    x    |    y    | Measure |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| A          | Left    | Right   | 1       |
| A          | Venstre | Hojre   | 3       |
                    ...
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My current simple join, which duplicates the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM _table s1
JOIN _table s2
ON s1.manager = s2.manager 
AND s1.x = s2.y
AND s2.y = s1.x
```

Please don't hesitate to ask for any clarification.

EDIT: Seemed like there was a 'consistency' in the naming of 'Left' and 'Right'. There's not.

Comment: Do you have any way to distinguish which of the rows should be preserved? For example, is always the `X` value with `positive` measure? Or is always the first row with measure bigger then the second row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY`:

The idea is to rearrange the columns (`x` and `y`), in this case alphabetically, and then use the arranged columns (`FirstCol` and `LastCol`) in your `GROUP BY`

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef106/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        FirstCol = CASE WHEN x <= y THEN x ELSE y END,
        LastCol = CASE WHEN x <= y THEN y ELSE x END
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    Manager,
    x = FirstCol,
    y = LastCol,
    Measure = SUM(Measure)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY Manager, FirstCol, LastCol
```

**Result**

```
| Manager |     x |      y | Measure |
|---------|-------|--------|---------|
|       A |  Left |  Right |       1 |
|       A | Left2 | Right2 |       3 |
```

---

Edit: This solution will retain the original column order if there is only one `xy` combination (no pair). Additionally, it will retain the order of the row with the higher `Measure` value:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba7a6/6/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        Manager,
        x,
        y,
        RN =    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY 
                        Manager,
                        CASE WHEN x <= y THEN x ELSE y END,
                        CASE WHEN x <= y THEN y ELSE x END
                    ORDER BY
                        Measure DESC
                ),

        Measure = SUM(Measure) OVER(
                    PARTITION BY 
                        Manager,
                        CASE WHEN x <= y THEN x ELSE y END,
                        CASE WHEN x <= y THEN y ELSE x END
                  )
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    Manager, x, y, Measure
FROM Cte
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: @Felix Pamittan : I just added a row like this `'A', 'Right3', 'Left3', 5`. [Please have a look at this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba7a6/1)

Comment: @Ullas, oh, you've used the query on my first post. I've updated it since. I'm sorry. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba7a6/4/0

Comment: Even I have updated the query.[please check this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba7a6/3).

Comment: @FelixPamittan:`Right3` should be `x` column right? I am not trying to prove that you are wrong. just for curiosity.

Comment: @Ullas, yup, that's the drawback of this query. The columns will be arranged regardless if there's a pair or not.

Comment: @FelixPamittan : great. Even i was trying to fix it up.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Manager] CHAR(1)
   ,[x] CHAR(8)
   ,[y] CHAR(8)
   ,[Measure] SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Manager], [x], [y], [Measure])
VALUES ('A', 'Left', 'Right', 10)
      ,('A', 'Right', 'Left', -9)
      ,('A', 'Left2', 'Right2', 4)
      ,('A', 'Right2', 'Left2', -1);

SELECT DS1.[Manager]
      ,DS1.[x] AS [x]
      ,DS2.[x] AS [y]
      ,DS1.[Measure] + DS2.[Measure] AS [Measure]
FROM @DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN @DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[x] = DS2.[y]
    AND DS1.[y] = DS2.[x]
    AND DS1.[Manager] = DS2.[Manager]
WHERE DS1.[Measure] > DS2.[Measure];
```

[image]